# PHP - How to get the key number from an XML object inside of a foreach loop

Tags: php, xml, object

```
$data = simplexml_load_file($source_url);
```

if I'm looping through some items that look like this

```
    [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => Justin Bieber and Chance the Rapper Collaborate
                        [link] => http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/absolutepunknet/~3/vn98Mqyr4_4/showthread.php
                        [pubDate] => Mon, 09 Dec 2013 07:37:44 GMT
                        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [category] => News
                        [guid] => http://www.absolutepunk.net/showthread.php?t=3576311
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [link] => http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/absolutepunknet/~3/IjS0KtTy8Ws/showthread.php
                        [pubDate] => Mon, 09 Dec 2013 07:06:56 GMT
                        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [category] => News
                        [guid] => http://www.absolutepunk.net/showthread.php?t=3576281
                    )
```

Using

---

```
foreach ($data->channel->item as $key => $value)
```

How can I access and potentially remove one of the objects, in this example, I'd like to remove [1] => SimpleXMLElementOjbect

I've tried doing it using value of $key but that just contains the word "item". Can't quite figure this one out.

Comment: Does `unset($data->channel->item[$key])` work inside the `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the item from the XML element (not the array item itself) you can do it this way:

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($element);
$dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
```

For removing array items @Dave Chen's answer should work (only outside the foreach loop I think)

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMDocument directly, DOMXpath to find nodes:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($rssFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

//fetch the second item into a list
$items = $xpath->evaluate('/rss/channel/item[2]');
foreach ($items as $item) {
  // remove the item from its parent node
  $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

In Xpath list positions start with 1 not 0. The index 1 in PHP is the position 2 in Xpath.